# Javascript div refresh

Tags: javascript, php, refresh

I am trying to refresh a php script to show updated content as a database updates.  I first built my php, then the code to refresh and then merge them.  However, the script doesn't update.  Anyone know why?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    if(document.getElementById('gallery') != null){
                        function showLots() {
                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            } else {
                                // code for IE6, IE5
                                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                    document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                }
                            }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php",true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        } 
                    }
                }, 3000);
            });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you've included jQuery, why wouldn't you use `$.ajax`, it's one of the best parts ?

Comment: Just learning how to do this.  Please share. I'm curious.

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="gallery"`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/mrv93on7/

Comment: @NormanBreau yes, gallery is there

Comment: Your code can be condensed to `setInterval(function () { $('#gallery').load('getuser.php'); }, 3000);`

Comment: @adeneo hmm. Not working.  Thanks, though.  I didn't know all that could be condensed. Now I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `function showLots()` is inside your `if (document.getElementById('gallery') != null)` conditional without the function actually executing.

Below is what your corrected code could could look like by moving the `function showLots()` definition up. `showLots()` is then called inside where you originally had the definition.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function showLots() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('gallery') !== null) {
                showLots();
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, still struggling.  I'm getting an unexpected token at 3000.

Comment: Thanks. Got it now. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You did not called method `showLots`, First define it outside the function and than call it in `setInterval`